# C# WPF gif black background

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, gif, transparent

I have a problem with Gif animation in MediaElement. Animation is OK, but transparent background is black plus I see all other frames. I tried other Gif and It was same.

There is my MediaElement:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="myGif" 
              Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              Margin="100,100,0,0" 
              MediaEnded="myGif_MediaEnded"  
              UnloadedBehavior="Manual" 
              LoadedBehavior="Play" 
              Source="animation.gif" Stretch="Fill"/>
```

When I use a Image tag - transparent is OK, but surprisingly animation don´t works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might consider using a small lib for this. Thomas Levesque has created a WpfAnimatedGif which is available as a Nuget package. Just type the following in Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package WpfAnimatedGif 

PM> Install-Package WpfAnimatedGif
Installing 'WpfAnimatedGif 1.4.13'.
Successfully installed 'WpfAnimatedGif 1.4.13'.
Adding 'WpfAnimatedGif 1.4.13' to AnimatedGIF.
Successfully added 'WpfAnimatedGif 1.4.13' to AnimatedGIF.
```

Let's then define a small GUI to test this lib out:

```
<Window x:Class="AnimatedGIF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="Hypnotize"
        xmlns:wpfanimated="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com"
        Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>    

        <Image wpfanimated:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="a_transparent_gif.gif"
               wpfanimated:ImageBehavior.RepeatBehavior="1"
               wpfanimated:ImageBehavior.AnimateInDesignMode="False"
               wpfanimated:ImageBehavior.AutoStart="True"              
               Height="300" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here we use the Image Control and apply the functionality that the library provides as an attached property. Source code is available on the Github page:

https://github.com/thomaslevesque/WpfAnimatedGif/blob/master/WpfAnimatedGif/ImageBehavior.cs

I have made available a sample solution here:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8EF5059044F781FC!40935&authkey=!AA7kju6NnsGzpB4&ithint=file%2czip

[image]

Now did we all forget how cool Animated GIFs once were considered?